# Woocommerce set and unset shipping based on Shipping Address Checked

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

UPDATED QUESTION AFTER Scriptonomy ANSWER BELOW

I have a woocommerce site in which I have a few different shipping options.  I need to hide and show these shipping options based on the "Ship to different address button being checked"

```
//remove local pickup
function ddc_hide_shipping( $rates, $package ) {

    unset( $rates['local_pickup'] );

    return $rates;
}

//check if needs shipping address so we can unset local pickup
function ddc_update_shipping_options($instance) {

    parse_str(html_entity_decode($instance), $postData);
    if ( @$postData['ship_to_different_address']  ) {
        add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'ddc_hide_shipping');
    } 
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'ddc_update_shipping_options');
```

Using the above code that got from help from Scriptonomy I am getting closer.   The problem I am having as this doesn't seem to work when the user checks and un checks the ship to different billing address.  This only works for me on first page load, not on every ajax call to update the order review area.

Thank you.

Comment: Still works every time for me! I am running the code from the templates functions.php file! where are you running yours from?

Comment: I have the code in my themes functions.php file as well.   What I am noticing is that if I change the shipping destination to default to shipping then when the page loads the local pickup gets removed.   However checking and unchecking the box which does make the AJAX call again does not reset the shipping rates.   Also if I set the default shipping destination to billing address then nothing works.     Thats where I was thinking something is weird in calling the filter as it only seems to run on first pass through for me.

Answer (score 0):

WC()->cart->needs_shipping_address() is based on store settings and item settings...so not ideal in this case, it will trigger every time in most cases.

Use the  $instance data instead which is a url encoded string.

1. Decode and parse the string then test for the ship_to_different_address option
2. Suppress invalid array index errors when the option is not selected

Here's your solution:

```
parse_str(html_entity_decode($instance), $postData);
if ( @$postData['ship_to_different_address']  ) {
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'ddc_hide_shipping', 10, 2 );
}
```

Put this in your action hook.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  You definitely got me going in the right direction.  The only problem it seems is that its too late to add a filter to woocommerce_package_rates at this point.  

What I ended up doing was move the template to my theme so I could add my own filter just before printing out the available methods and I then filter out the method I don't want.

Comment: I don't quite get your 'it's too late' logic. It worked quite well for me with no issues. I already tested it.

Comment: Sorry about my comment you are correct.   The problem comes when the opposite occurs.   When they uncheck we need to put the shipping method back into the rates array.  Thats where I was getting confused.  No matter what I try to do I can't get that process to happen.

Comment: If I remember correctly, it worked for me as well. The shipping methods array updates every time a change occurs. In other words the shipping methods are regenerated on every Ajax call.

Comment: Actually did more testing.  I changed the settings in the shipping backend to default to billing address and the above doesn't work anymore.   

Basically it seems like it works the first time through because we can call the woocommerce package rates filter when the page first loads.  But I think its too late in the process to run that filter. when the order review section updates

Comment: Updated my original question to better reflect what I am trying to say.